# Как передать значения из формы в контроллер?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
и так,у меня есть jsp страница с некой формой ввода



    <%@page contentType="text/html;charset = UTF-8" language="java" %>
    <%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <jsp:useBean id="Type" class="spring.example.config.TypeValuesConfig"/>
    <html>
    <head>
        Title
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="/addBoxEntity/${box.id}">
        <h2>Information about BoxEntity</h2>

        <p><input type="text" placeholder="colour" name="colour"></p>
        <p><input type="hidden" placeholder="id" name="id"></p>
        <p><input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name" value="${box.name}"></p>
        <p><input type="number" placeholder="weight" name="weight"></p>
        <p><input type="number" placeholder="memory" name="memory"></p>
        <select name="type" id="type">
            <c:forEach items="${Type.values}" var="type">
                <option value="${type}">${type}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="save">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

есть контроллер,который ее принимает

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/addBoxEntity/{box}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addBoxEntity(@PathVariable Long box, Info info) {
        System.out.println(info.toString());
        boxService.add(box,info);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Service class:

```
  public void add(Long boxId, Info info) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(info);
        Box box=session.get(Box.class,boxId);
        box.getInfo().add(info);
        session.save(box);
```

Pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INFO")

public class Info {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "memory")
    private Long memory;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private Type type;
    @Column(name = "colour")
    private String color;
    @Column(name = "weight")
    private Double weight;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "box_id", nullable = true)
    private Box box;
```

получаю ошибку

> Field error in object 'info' on field 'box': rejected value [1]; codes [typeMismatch.info.box,typeMismatch.box,typeMismatch.spring.example.model.Box,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [info.box,box]; arguments []; default message [box]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'spring.example.model.Box' for property 'box'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'spring.example.model.Box' for property 'box': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]

Comment: По-хорошему, параметр `Info info` надо пометить аннотацией `@RequestBody`

Answer (score 0):

Вы добавили библиотеку тэгов sringform, но не использовали её

```
<form method="post" action="/addBoxEntity/${box.id}"> ---> <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="info"> // и добавить info в модель в методе контроллера, который направляет на эту jsp

<input name="color".. ---> <form:input path="color"..
```